# uploading a new theme to live server

Tags: php, hosting

i've to change live version of a theme from live server.i'm given root folder of wordprss which contains all the folders of  wordpress itself alongwith all the theme files and plugins etc and of course db file . so now should i replace whole wordpress folder that contains wp-admin/content also  or  i should upload theme and plugins and then setup the database .

Please help as its critical to update live site and doing it for first time

Answer (score 0):

As I have written in your post at StackOverflow board:

Please look at [Upload localhost changes to live server](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169890/upload-localhost-changes-to-live-server/169931#169931)

If you are only making file changes, you should copy the live site and set it up on a local wordpress server. On the local wordpress server, just edit the theme as you like, and when you made your changes. Upload only the theme to your live site.

If you are also making database changes, please read the link in the top of my answer.

Remember to make backup, always make backup, backup is 1. priority in every case. If you screw up, make sure to get back online as fast as possible.

You can use a plugin as 'Duplicator' https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ to copy your live wordpress installation.

Comment: i'm taking site from one host to another not from lcoalhost  i cant make changes to site on localhost its already really a complex one ,

Comment: Use duplicator to copy the website from host A to host B

Comment: no i cant depend on a plugin , just confirm if i should upload all  files for wordpress itself  like wp-content / admin etc or should i replace only theme files and plugins etc , its really critical

Comment: It depends on if you have database changes or not - if you do, you have to move the whole from host A to host B, but meanwhile, you can't let users on your live site to make changes (insertions/modifcations to database).